# Asana * Wufoo : Advanced integration

Tags: asana, wufoo

I am working on "Advanced integration" of a forms from Wufoo to Asana. SO far I have followed the Asana guide - https://asana.com/guide/help/api/wufoo
Guide is excellent and everything within the guide work as it says, but I need to go a bit further.

I notice that there is a bit of symbols that asana recognize from the forms( like quotes"" , equal ==, question mark ?), example of multiple choice menu:

```
"Chose person" == "asana tag" ? 1559453678421
"Chose person" == "asana person" ? blablabla@something.org
```

So in the following example I can have a multi choice menu that can assign task to a person and/or put a tag.
If I add a second person, that person become a follower, which is great.

My goal:
I want to make the form filler to add its email address, and that email address to be add as follower of the task.

What I know:
I have so far talked with Wufoo support and they told me that the text from the form goes in a straight text form to Asana, and asana actually recognize the form and create the specific tasks, for example:

```
<strong>This become BOLD text in asana</strong>
```

I keep on looking for the rest of the recognized symbols, but without success so far. If you have any kind of information regarding the "Advanced integration" I would love to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a 2 workarounds to make this work for me.

Workaround 1

So far I have discover that asana recognize "hide" CSS Layout and the field labels : project,tag,assignee,follower . If these values are true then to make this editable I add a Wufoo form Rule that can show/hide fields. for example :

```
If "Email" contains "@" show "assignee"
```

And that rule does not change the CSS Layout Keyword "hide" so the form is send the same way with the only difference that the "hide" field is actually visible and that make it easily editable.

Workaround 2

By keeping the fields hide you can still edit them with "URL Modifications ". So basically have 2 forms linked together, so the first form fill up information that is send to the second form within the URL, so the fields remain hidden but being filled up by the URL. - I have not played with that much but Wufoo support briefly explain to me that its possible

URL Modification reference - http://help.wufoo.com/articles/en_US/SurveyMonkeyArticleType/URL-Modifications

Answer (score 2):

(I work at Asana.)  Right now we only support routing through fields that are hidden (have the "hide" classname) with our Wufoo integration, but your use-case is very interesting.  I'll take a look and see if we can enable this.

Comment: I have found a workaround but I would really love to know if you enable some more features for integration so I can play even further with it.

Comment: I will make a note to update this answer when we do :-)